# How to strip characters from string after and including the question mark?

Tags: bash

I am sure 200% something like this has been asked but by google skills are eluding me and I need a solid example as I am getting all sorts of errors perhaps on escaping the ?.  I thought I could do something like

```
${var1|?*|}
```

as I want to take

```
asldkjljewrewr?adflksjfdljksdf
```

and strip it down to

```
asldkjljewrewr
```

using bash script.

Comment: `var='asldkjljewrewr?adflksjfdljksdf'; echo "${var%\?*}"` The `?` needs escaping since it is a special character to the shell, which means a single string like a dot `.` in regex

Comment: `echo "${var1%%\?*}"` should work

Comment: maybe spliting the variable woulb de an option. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it is exactly what you were looking for, but one could do it using the `cut` command:

```
#!/bin/bash

var1="asldkjljewrewr?adflksjfdljksdf"
var2="$(cut -d "?" -f1 <<< "$var1")"
echo "$var2"
# asldkjljewrewr
```

Comment: works for me....eh, make it work, make it better ;). thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you were trying to use `${parameter%%pattern}`:

```
var1=asldkjljewrewr?adflksjfdljksdf
echo=${var1%%\?*}
```

Notice the need for escaping the `?` - otherwise it will be considered as "any character" in the glob.

You can find all supported forms of parameter substitution in the [Parameter Expansion section](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) of the Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide.